# Overlay an element of view

Tags: android, listview, android-framelayout

I have this layout for a fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include layout="@layout/header" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and this is header:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout >
```

Now when button is pressed, "box" should be populated and become visible, and box overlay the rest of views (in my case listview). Now when i press button ox does not overlay listview, but take a portion of screen (and listview moves down).
How can i do? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, and put the `FrameLayout` after the `ListView` in xml ( to place the header over the list):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include layout="@layout/header" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```